# Как объединить 2 интерфейса?

Tags: java, android, ооп, интерфейс

```
etEmail.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        checkBtnContinue(s);
    }
});

etPass.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        checkBtnContinue(s);
    }
});
```

Как видно, оба элемента делают одно и тоже, как объединить этот код, чтобы красиво смотрелось и читалось.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

вынести код за пределы метода

```
TextWatcher tw = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        checkBtnContinue(s);
    }
});
etEmail.addTextChangedListener(tw);
etPass.addTextChangedListener(tw);
```